# Telegram Bot running on PyTelegramBotAPI is incorrectly getting forwarded messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am forwarding messages to bot. Then bot simple prints it to my console *(for the first time)*. Then, let's look at the example:

**FORWARDING:**
1
2
3
4
5

**BOT OUTPUTS:**
2
1
4
3
5

The main problem is that the hierarchy of these messages is wrong. And it's always different, it can be even correct, but rarely...

Question:
**How to correctly get all messages with correct hierarchy?**

*Code that I use:*

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.forward_from != None) # handles only forwarded messages
def newPost(message):
    print(message.text)
```

*Info:
Python 3, PyTelegramBotAPI*

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly? You forward a message `1 2 3 4 5` to the bot and it prints them in random sequence on the console? For some reason, I can't reproduce this problem (even with your code as is). It outputs your example case on console as expected `1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Doesn't each message have unique incremental `id`?

Answer (score 0):

if you using pytelegrambotapi you shoud type like this (below handler)
and if you send numbers in 1 message

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text, <keyboard>)
```

else - if you send numbers in more message -

trying to concatenation several messages to tuple and send it.